# Implementing an OR constraint in Google OR-tools?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, or-tools

I'm trying to solve a variant of the transportation problem with a constraint which makes me able to specify the amount of supplies a truck should take to from a certain source towards a certain destination.

For example:

```
Source S1 has a supply of 40.
Source S2 has a supply of 40.
Source S3 has a supply of 20.
Destination D1 has a a demand of 40.
```

I want to be able to make it so that demand of D1 is fulfilled by TWO suppliers who each deliver 20.

In constraint form I think this would be:

```
S1D1 = 0 OR 20
S2D1 = 0 OR 20
S3D1 = 0 or 20

S1D1 + S2D1 + S3D1 = 40
```

But I have no idea how to implement the OR constraint in Google OR-tools.
I think I have to look at a mixed integer integer solver, but I can't find any examples or documentation that would solve my problem.

Comment: So what are you using? CP, SAT-CP, MIP? There are many solvers in ortools. No code here, so hard to help.

Comment: I don't think an OR constraint is the correct approach here. If the maximum flow of a link is the capacity of a truck, you just have capacities on the arcs `x(i,j)`: `x(i,j) <= CAP`. These are just bounds on decision variables. Advice: it is really essential to first write down the mathematical model before writing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erwin you are right.

I used a mixed integer solver and used the following constraints.

Constraints:

A variable is an integer and between 0 and 1 (so it's 1 or 0).

20 S1D1 + 20 S2D1 + 20 S3D1 = 40

this was a simplified example, in my problem I actually have more destinations.
To make sure a source doesn't provide more than it has the following constraint was used (use 2 destinations as example, Destination 2 has a demand of 40 provided by once source):

20 S1D1 + 40 S1D2 <= 40 (repeat this for all sources)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi want to assign a Boolean variable how do I do that using Python wrapper?